# Conditional action segue if the condition is met

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to set a conditional action segue, which means when the user enter the username and password and click on login button, he will see another screen, else it will shows a UIAlertView, containing the error message.

Here is my code for the login method, it works fine, it checks the username and password, if they match, it shows " Success " , else it shows " error " in output :

> ```
> -(IBAction)login 
> {
> NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.example.com/db.php?username=%@&pass=%@",email.text,password.text]];
> NSString *response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
> NSLog(@"response %@",response);
> }
> ```

**What I want :**

- When the user enters the login info correctly, he will enter to the app.
- When the user enters false login info, he will see an error message using (UIAlertView).

Comment: I don't know why I am getting (-1) knowing that the question is very clear and straight forward, I am a newbie and I don't know many things, you should encourage the newbie instead of discouraging them !

Comment: Tip: Ask clear questions concerning about a specific problem. If you just list your needs no one will do the work for you.

Comment: @Desdenova I try my best to ask clear questions, you should know as a newbie, I don't know many keywords, so I can not be very specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate entries when user taps on login button,

```
 -(IBAction)login  {
    if(email.text.length > 0 && password.text.length > 0) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.example.com/db.php?username=%@&pass=%@",email.text,password.text]];
        NSString *response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        if ([response isEqualToString:@"success"]) {
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc1 animated:YES];
        } else {
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
        }
    } else {
        // show error alert message
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you ! can you tell me please how, I can transfer the user to the other screen conditionaly ?

Comment: Here conditionally means what? can you explain me in what are those conditions?

Comment: I mean for example, if the login is successful, then It will show another screen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !! Should I add something in storyboard too, in order to match the code ? for example adding an identifier, or doing action segue... ?

Comment: Yes, you should create the different views using storyboard and than instantiate them at the time of using.

Comment: By the way it says : "Use of undeclared indetifier vc1" what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

[image]

call this

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToEditController" sender:self];
```

## pragma mark - Segue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

   if (<#condition#>) {
        <#statements-if-true#>
    } else {
        <#statements-if-false#>
    }

}
```